# TVF output is missing computed column from view it references

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions, calculated-columns

I have a view with a computed column, and a TV-function on top of it, (simplified) as follows:

```
create view     dbo.vwEvent_A   as
select  ea.idEvent, ea.dtEvent, ea.cSys, ..
    ,   sd.sSGJR + '-' + right('0' + cast(ea.tiBtn as varchar), 2) [sSGJRB] 
    from    tbEvent_A ea
    inner join  ..
    left outer join vwDevice sd on  sd.cSys = ea.cSys   ..

create function     dbo.fnEventA_GetTopByRoom
(
    @cSys       char( 1 )
,   @tiGID      tinyint
)
returns table
as
return
    select  top 1   *
        from    vwEvent_A
        where   bActive > 0 and cSys = @cSys
    order   by  siIdx desc, tElapsed
```

When executing the function i not only get 1 column less of data, but also column headers slide down (skipping the computed column).  **However, most miraculously, data from all columns stays put!**

[image: executing 'select *' from source data, view directly and from function]
[image: expanded (and wrapped) portion, showing moved column headers and data in place]

I could live with the fact that computed column is "discriminated" and pushed out from the resultset, but it's pushing out only column header, messing up everything using this function, because now returned columns have wrong datatypes.  No docs i could find mention anything related.

**Anybody knows what's going on??**

And any ideas how to fix it?  I'll replace function call with explicit `select * from vwEvent_A` (adding necessary conditions), but the main reason for this func's existence was code reuse.. [see below]

EDIT: To dot the i-s (for someone reading this later on),
- View is indeed reused by other objects (which did not exhibit any similar issues, at least so far).  The computed column being the culprit was added by the recent revision.
- The func exists to provide a single highest priority row, which is then `OUTER APPLY`-ed in another sproc.  I did not find a better/easier way to do that.
- Refreshing the func (by `ALTER FUNC`) and even re-creating it (by `DROP FUNC / CREATE FUNC`) did not have any effect (difference in the output).

Comment: Does this also happen with other SQL clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the computed column has been added to the view since the function was created.

Two-part solution:

1. Run `sp_refreshsqlmodule` to update the view and function's metadata, starting with the view:

   ```
    EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule N'dbo.vwEvent_A';
    EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule N'dbo.fnEventA_GetTopByRoom';
   ```
2. [Stop using `SELECT *` in your views and functions](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). This is precisely one of the reasons we don't do this. Also suggest creating both objects `WITH SCHEMABINDING` so that it is much harder for the schema to get out of sync (you want it to be hard to mess with the output of objects that other objects rely on).

Comment: I'm confused. On the one hand, you solved OP's problem with a simple `EXEC`, but on the other hand you're telling him not to use the feature (`SELECT *`) that makes the solution so easy. What alternative do you suggest?

Comment: @Gabe I don't know that they're mutually exclusive. I suggest not using `SELECT *` in the first place, then the solution isn't required because the problem doesn't happen. If someone breaks their leg jumping out of a tree, I'm going to advise them to not jump out of a tree again, but I'll call the ambulance first...

Comment: Well, if you were the OP, how would you create the `fnEventA_GetTopByRoom` function to not use `SELECT *`?

Comment: @Gabe I probably wouldn't bother to use the function, to be honest. Don't know what it really adds except shortening the where clause slightly. If I really found the reuse compelling (I don't), I would create the function and the view with schemabinding, and hard-code the columns instead of using SELECT *. Unless you know something about the dynamic nature of the schema that I don't...

Comment: Better yet, I'd drop the view altogether, and move the logic to the function.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, i should've mentioned it in the post;  i did think of func definition getting out of sync, since indeed `vwEvent_A.sSGJRB` was added by the last revision.  So i tried `ALTER FUNC` to refresh it, and then even `DROP FUNC / CREATE FUNC` to completely renew it.  Neither produced any difference in the output!  I also thought of `select *` and expanded it, listing all view's columns explicitly in the func definition.  **Still no joy!**  I'm going to try your suggestion #1, but wonder shouldn't re-creating an object take care of object's metadata, cached execution plans and the like?

Comment: @Astrogator should, yes, but I can't reproduce your scenario and there must be some other variable here that I can't see.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thank you!  Calling `sp_refreshsqlmodule` worked!  So what, now it's a necessary step for all modified objects during every revision??  Agree with your #2 point in general.  Upon reviewing the func i'll restate its origins as a source for `OUTER APPLY` "join" in another sproc (that's the only way i found to bind to the single row returned by the func).  View is reused, surprisingly so far i didn't have any similar issues (possibly because dependents have all been revised).  But that again raises my question of **why `ALTER`ing an object doesn't take care of the cached shtuff?**

Comment: @Astrogator because SQL Server doesn't have a good "follow all dependencies and update all things that might break" story. If you keep your schema more stable and stop using `SELECT *`, this problem should be a lot rarer...